# Initialize an object built from a class with a specific dictionary

Tags: python, class, inheritance, dictionary, python-2.x

The goal is to build a class with an `__init__` method that will allow to create objects which will be initialized with a specific dictionary.

**Details:**

A file `mydicts.py` is a collection of various dictionaries.
The object built from the class that I intent to create will be initialized to one of the dictionaries from `mydicts.py`.

`mydicts.py` example:

```
dict1 = {k1:v1, k2:v2,...,kn:vn}
dict2 = {k1:v1, k2:v2,...,km:vm}
etc.
```

My attempts:

```
class Example(dict):
    def __init__(self, dictx):
        self.dictx = getattr(__import__("mydicts", fromlist=['m']), dictx)
```

Results:

```
e = Example('dict1')
print e
{}        # <- got empty dictionary. Want {k1:v1, k2:v2,...,kn:vn}
```

The goal is to create objects such that:

```
a = Example(dict1)
print a
# {k1:v1, k2:v2,...,kn:vn}

b = Example(dict2)
print b
# {k1:v1, k2:v2,...,km:vm}
```

Comment: for printing the information about any object you need to define a `__str__` method inside the class. try printing the self.dictx in that method, it would be implicitly called, when you print the instance of that class

Comment: I have to accept @iCodez's solution as he was more detailed but it is around the same idea as you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you did not define a custom [`__str__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) for your class, `print` is calling the `__str__` method of the parent class `dict`.  Moreover, this is causing Python to print the empty dictionary created by the parent class in `dict.__new__` instead of the dictionary that you have stored in `self.dictx`.

Because your class inherits from `dict`, you should be passing the dictionary returned by `getattr` to the `__init__` method of the parent class.  You can use [`super`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-dict) for this:

```
class Example(dict):
    def __init__(self, dictx):
        dct = getattr(__import__("__main__", fromlist=['m']), dictx)
        super(Example, self).__init__(dct)
```

This will initialize the parent class with data taken from `dct`.  In other words, the empty dictionary has been replaced with the dictionary returned by `getattr`.  So, when `print` calls the parent's `__str__` method, the correct output will be given:

```
>>> dict1 = {'k1':'v1', 'k2':'v2', 'kn':'vn'}
>>> class Example(dict):
...     def __init__(self, dictx):
...         dct = getattr(__import__("__main__", fromlist=['m']), dictx)
...         super(Example, self).__init__(dct)
...
>>> e = Example('dict1')
>>> print e
{'k2': 'v2', 'k1': 'v1', 'kn': 'vn'}
>>>
```

---

An alternate solution would be to define a custom `__str__` method for your class that returns `self.dictx` as a string:

```
class Example(dict):
    def __init__(self, dictx):
        self.dictx = getattr(__import__("mydicts", fromlist=['m']), dictx)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.dictx)
```

Note however that if you use this approach, there isn't really a reason to inherit from `dict` since your class is not a new type of dictionary; it just has a dictionary stored as an attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are making this far more complicated than it need be. Noting [the manual says](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__):

> Direct use of `__import__()` is rare, except in cases where you want to import a module whose name is only known at runtime.

But you do know the module name at loading time, your data definition just has too many variable names. Much clearer would be `my_dicts.py`:

```
my_dicts = [
    {k1:v1, k2:v2,...,kn:vn},
    {k1:v1, k2:v2,...,km:vm},
    …
]
```

and `example.py`:

```
import my_dicts

class Example(dict):
    def __init__(self, n):
        """Returns an Example instance loaded with the nth element
           of my_dict."""
        super(Example, self).__init__(my_dicts.my_dicts[n])
```

Comment: Actually, the name is the dictionary is known at runtime and dictionaries are named. Nevertheless, nice solution!

Comment: Then I fall back to the CS101 maxim that whenever you have a set of variables of the form {d1, d2, … d10000} you actually have a list (array) in disguise. Using a pseudo-list severely limits the flexibility and extensibility of the data, for if you need d10001, code needs to be changed to support it instead of mere data. Also, the `__import__` method is cryptic and will send the next reader off to the manual and still wonder what `fromlist=` means in context.